# ImageButton change: the new image is plotted on top of original image

Tags: android, image, onclick, imagebutton

I am trying to change the image of an ImageButton when the button is pressed. Here is my code:

in my `activity_main.xml` I have:

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/my_btn"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_icon1" />
```

In my `MainActivity.java` I have:

```
    int myBtnState = 0; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.my_btn:
            changeIcon();
            break;
    ...
    private void changeIcon() {
         if(myBtnState == 0) { 
           myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_icon1);
           myBtnState = 1;
         } else {
           myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_icon2);
           myBtnState = 0;
         }
     }
```

when I run this code when I press the button, it looks like the first time `btn_icon1` is drawn on top of itself 2 times as it has a semi-transparent background I see it gets darker. And next time I press the button `btn_icon2` is drawn on top of `btn_icon1`. I expected that using this code the icons to be changed, not drawn on top of each other. Is there anything I am doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

I was setting the background of the image when I did:

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_icon1);
```

Instead, I should do:

```
myButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_icon1);
```